# Анимированый переход в активити

Tags: android

Ребята,во всех активити переходы работают с анимацией,а вот в одном активити,где у меня стоит таймер на выполнение,анимация не работает.

```
package com.example.com.shcherbuk;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Constants {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        startApp();
    }

    private void startApp(){
        Timer myTimer = new Timer(); // Создаем таймер
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // Определяем задачу
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WebActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(KEY_INTENT,URL_MY_WEBSITE);
                //Запуск Браузера
                //startActivity(intent);

                //Запуск Main
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
                //finish();
            }
        }, 3L * 1000);
    }
}
```

Почему здесь не работает анимация при переходе из одной активити в другую, и как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потоки помогли решить эту проблему.
Вот код:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
    }
}, 3*1000);
```